# Hide part of UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have 3 UIBezierPath with 2 circle and a line running from 1 circle's center to the other and it looks like the bottom picture.  I want to hide the part of the line inside the circle like the top picture.  Is there any easy way to do this?

My strategy would be to draw a invisible line from the centers and then draw a black line from the circumference of the 2 circles since I know the slopes etc but it seems like too much work.
[image]

```
    private func pathForBoxCircle1() -> UIBezierPath {

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter:circle1BoxCurrentCenter, radius: 25, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(2*M_PI), clockwise: false)
        //circlePath.fill()
        pathBoxCircle1Global = circlePath

        return circlePath
    }

    private func pathForBoxCircle2() -> UIBezierPath {

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter:circle2BoxCurrentCenter, radius: 25, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(2*M_PI), clockwise: false)
        //circlePath.fill()
        pathBoxCircle2Global = circlePath

        return circlePath
    }
    private func pathForHorizonLine() -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: circle1BoxCurrentCenter)
        path.addLine(to: circle2BoxCurrentCenter)
        path.lineWidth = 5.0
        //pathHorizonLineGlobal = path


        return path
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        pathForBoxCircle1().stroke()
        pathForBoxCircle2().stroke() // same as stroke()
        pathForHorizonLine().stroke()


    }
```

Comment: fill the color in the circle?

Comment: @HMHero I want circle to be see through

Comment: Can you show your code to draw the path? Can you not draw the line from the rightmost part of the circle to the leftmost part of the other circle?

Comment: @Ali The line should be the same line as if I were to draw from 1 center to the other center just with the part inside cut off so I don't control which side it goes to just depends where the circles are compare to eachother.  The slope should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix transparent and opaque lines in the same shape. You are going to have to draw 2 circles and then the line segment from the outside of the first circle to the outside of the 2nd circle.

To do that you'll need trig, or perhaps Pythagoras, to calculate the coordinates of the points where your connecting lines intersect your 2 circles.

If C1 is your first circle, C2 is your 2nd circle, C1 is at (C1.x, C1.y), C2 is at (C2.x, C2.y), the radius of C1 is R1, and the radius of C2 is R2, then the pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
angle1 = atan2(C1.y - C2y, C1.x - C2.x)

angle2 = atan2(C2.y - C1.y, C2.x - C1.x)

xOffset1 = R1 * cos(angle1)
yOffset1 = R1 * sin(angle1)

point1 = (C1.x + xOffset1, C1.y + yOffset1)

xOffset2 = R2 * cos(angle2)
yOffset2 = R2 * sin(angle2)

point2 = (C2.x + xOffset2, C2.y +  yOffset2)
```

Draw your circles, then draw lines between point1 and point2.

(Note that my trig is a little rusty, and that I sketched this out on a piece of scratch paper. I think it's correct, but it's completely untested.)